# How do I record audio at a super low bit rate on iOS?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, audio-recording, avaudiorecorder

I've been trying to record audio on iOS using `AVAudioRecorder`. Below are some of the settings I've tried on a iOS 10.0.2, iPhone 6.

```
16khz, 1 channel, CBR, AVAudioQualityMin, 8000 bitrate - didn’t record
16khz, 1 channel, CBR, AVAudioQualityMin, 8192 bitrate - didn’t record
16khz, 1 channel, CBR, AVAudioQualityMin, 10000 bitrate - didn’t record
16khz, 1 channel, CBR, AVAudioQualityMin, 10000 bitrate/channel - didn’t record
16khz, 1 channel, CBR, AVAudioQualityMin, 11264 bitrate/channel - didn’t record

(only 2 successful recordings)
16khz, 1 channel, CBR, AVAudioQualityMin, 12000 bitrate/channel - 69s, 113KB 1.63KB/s 
16khz, 1 channel, constant, Min, 12000 bitrate - 31s, 51KB 1.6KB/s
```

Here's the code for initializing the settings

```
- (void)_initRecorderSettings
{
    self.recorderSettings = ({
        NSMutableDictionary *settings = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC]
                    forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:12000.0]
                    forKey:AVSampleRateKey];
        [settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]
                    forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

        // Encoder
        [settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin]
                    forKey:AVEncoderAudioQualityKey];
        [settings setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:12000]
                    forKey:AVEncoderBitRateKey];
        [settings setValue:AVAudioBitRateStrategy_Constant
                    forKey:AVEncoderBitRateStrategyKey];
        settings;
    });
}
```

Here's the code for recording

```
   if (self.isRecording) {
        return;
    }

    NSError *recorderInitError;
    self.audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:outputFileUrl
                                                     settings:self.recorderSettings
                                                        error:&recorderInitError];
    if (recorderInitError) {
        return;
    }

    self.isRecording = [self.audioRecorder record];
```

In the findings mentioning 'didn't record' - `[self.audioRecorder record];` returns FALSE. (recorderInitError is always nil)

**I want to be able to record at 8kbps, why am I not able to do it? If it's not possible, can VBR help with lowering the size of the recorded file?**

Comment: is it possible to give us how you generate the dictionary for recorder settings?

Comment: @Bluewings I've updated the question